# Docker pull request limits for Docker Hub registry

Tags: docker, dockerhub

According to Docker forum there is no bandwidth or request limit for public Docker Hub repositories. (https://forums.docker.com/t/is-there-a-bandwidth-limit-and-or-pull-limit-on-free-public-repositories/3882)

Does that same rule apply for the private Docker Hub repositories as well? There must be at least some kind of theoretical limit? Or does it mean that I could make requests every second to check if new version is available in Docker Hub registry? That would alone generate 86400 requests per day.

Edit: asked same question on Docker Hub forums: https://forums.docker.com/t/is-there-a-bandwidth-limit-and-or-pull-limit-on-free-private-repositories/38815

Answer (score 2):

Got a response from Docker representative and according to them they only charge from the amount of repositories. So there should be no pull limits and neither bandwidth limits. Same rules apply for the public free repositories as well as private repositories. Their amount of repository pricing is found here: https://hub.docker.com/billing-plans/

Answer (score 1):

Docker has enabled download rate limits for pull requests on Docker Hub:

https://docs.docker.com/docker-hub/download-rate-limit/

Docker will gradually introduce these rate limits, with full effects starting from November 2nd, 2020.